# Plot by unique values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df = 

A   B   C   D
0   11  95  53
1   11  21  20
2   22  21  84
3   22  72  29
4   33  46  98
5   33  23  42
```

Based on unique values of column `B` plot `C` & `D` in different colors. I mean:

for number 11 in `B` we have `C` & `D` (95, 53) and (21,20) - plot them in a red color (or any color).

for number 22 in `B` we have `C` & `D` (21, 84) and (72,29) - plot them in a color (different color).

repeat for the whole `df`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for key, d in df.groupby('B'):
    d.plot(x='C', y='D', ax=ax, label=key)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. In real data I have a lot of line, so colors are repeating. Any suggestion how to create unique colors?

Answer (score 1):

`seaborn` can be very useful for this sort of plot. Grouping is accomplished with the `hue` parameter, and you can specify a color palette with the correct number of distinct colors.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(x='C', y='D', hue='B', data=df,
             palette=sns.color_palette('cubehelix', df.B.nunique()))
```

[image]